# What is the domain of $f(x)=\sqrt{2x-8}$?

Tags: functions, radicals

Is the domain of $f(x)$ simply any number, but in [this Khan Academy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4h54s7BBPpA) video, it said the domain is $x \geqslant 4$.

Comment: If the function is defined R$\rightarrow $ R than the expression under radical must be non negative otherwise it will generate a complex number

Comment: Hence 2x-8$\ge 0$ and $x\ge 4$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If function is defined on real numbers , then the square root expression must be non negative , because $\sqrt -a$ for positive $a$ is not defined in real numbers

So expression under radical is $2x-8$

Therefore $$2x-8\ge 0$$ it gives $$ x\ge 4$$ so the domain is $$x\in [4,\infty)$$

Comment: If $a=-1$, then $\sqrt{-a}$ is well defined. In no way $-a$ is supposed to denote a negative number.

Comment: If $a \leq 0$, then $\sqrt{-a}$ is defined.  Just say that the square root of a negative number is not defined in the real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

$2x-8 \geqslant 0$
implies $x\geqslant 4$.

Comment: “implies” is not the same as “if and only if”.

Comment: Here we can write "if and only if" in place of "implies".

Comment: Then let us do that...

Answer (score 1):

If $x<4$, then $2x-8<0$ and $\sqrt{2x-8}$ doesn't exist. *(At least, it has no generic definition and it won't be a real number even if you build an extension of square root on negative, or even complex, numbers.)*

Thus you can only compute $f(x)$ when $x\geq 4$, that's why the domain of $f$ is $[4,+\infty)$

Comment: If you type x \geq 4 when you are in math mode, you will obtain $x \geq 4$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig : thanks, done.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is a real-valued function of a real variable, unless otherwise specified, its domain is understood to be the set of all real numbers $x$ such that $f(x)$ is real-valued. For a square root function, this means the radicand, the term inside the radical, must be nonnegative since no negative number has a real-valued square root.  Hence, for $x$ to be in the domain of $f$,
\begin{align*}
2x - 8 & \geq 0\\
2x & \geq 8\\
x & \geq 4
\end{align*}
Thus, the domain of $f$ is $\text{Dom}_f = [4, \infty)$.